# How to create a popup menu below navigationitems in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I want to create a popup menu like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71l4C.png)

and it has a clear full screen overlay, when touch the overlay, popup menu will dismiss.

I tried add an overlay to root view, and add a menu list view to it, hardcoding position and frame for it, align with navigationItem then create a EnvironmentObject to store the overlay's toggle.
After this, I arrived my goal, but I think it was kind of mechanical, so my question is, is there has a good way to do this? like just use view modifier, or another with less step?

This is my root view:

```
struct Root : View { 
    TabbedView {
        NavigationView {
           HomePage()
        }
    }.overlay(...)  <-- add a overlay at root view.
}

struct HomePage : View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            List {...}
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Home")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: 
            Button(action: {
                // show popup menu
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer can help you. there have showing popUp using zstack.
Possibly a duplicate of >

> [Present Modal fullscreem SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58023147/present-modal-fullscreem-swiftui)

Comment: Please post relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.