# Present Modal fullscreem SwiftUI

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swiftui, modalviewcontroller

how can i present a modal that will take up the fullscreen and can't be dismissed by swiping it down? Currently I am using `.sheet` on a view to present a modal that is dismissible.

I haven't noticed any beta changes in Xcode that changes this behavior.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56756318/swiftui-presentationbutton-with-modal-that-is-full-screen

Comment: @maddy they're using UIViewControllers. I want to purely use Views

Comment: It's possible to disable dismiss see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398353/is-it-possible-to-make-a-modal-non-dismissible-in-swiftui/57399626#57399626
But Modal is not meant to be full screen. Maybe you need to present your next view in a different way.

Comment: @LuLuGaGa i just want the view to be presented fullscreen

Answer (score 17):

## SwiftUI 1.0

I'm not sure if this what you'd want to go with but it's possible to create your own modal screen by using the ZStack and a state variable to control the hiding/showing of it.

### Code

```
struct CustomModalPopups: View {
    @State private var showingModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text("Custom Popup").font(.largeTitle)
                
                Text("Introduction").font(.title).foregroundColor(.gray)
                
                Text("You can create your own modal popup with the use of a ZStack and a State variable.")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding().font(.title).layoutPriority(1)
                    .background(Color.orange).foregroundColor(Color.white)
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingModal = true
                }) {
                    Text("Show popup")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            
            // The Custom Popup is on top of the screen
            if $showingModal.wrappedValue {
                // But it will not show unless this variable is true
                ZStack {
                    Color.black.opacity(0.4)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
                    // This VStack is the popup
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Text("Popup")
                            .bold().padding()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color.orange)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            self.showingModal = false
                        }) {
                            Text("Close")
                        }.padding()
                    }
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(20).shadow(radius: 20)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Example

(Excerpt from "SwiftUI Views" book)
[image: SwiftUI Views Book Excerpt]
So here, your popup is small, but you can adjust the dimensions to make it fullscreen with the frame modifier that is on that VStack.

Comment: That's not ideal to always use zstacks. For example if you erase on the new view UserDefaults.standard and the oldview behind depends on it, the app will crash.

Comment: Yeah, this was all I could think of at this time for your problem. I'll keep a lookout for other options.

Comment: Black transparent overlay doesn't overlap with navigation bar. It appears under navigation bar